# C# Null Conditional Operator with nullable datetime

Tags: c#

I am trying to learn use the null conditional operator but can't seem to get it to work,

```
string datetest = DOInfolist[i].RentalItem.SimCard.DateIn[u].Value.ToShortDateString() ?? "Empty";
```

`DateIn` is a list of nullable `DateTime` (`List<Datetime?>`) .

I did debugging and all the values in `DateIn[u]` give null.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The `null` value is referenced at `DOInfolist[i].RentalItem.SimCard.DateIn[u].**Value**`, so much before the `??`

Comment: Add a  `?` - `DOInfolist[i].RentalItem.SimCard.DateIn[u]?.ToShortDateString() ?? "Empty"`. Now the result returned will be `null` from each of the `?` and the execution chain stops when a `null` is encountered, this will prevent the line from throwing an `NRE` (unless something earlier in the chain is also null).

Comment: I think you're confusing the Null Coalescing operator with the Null Conditional one.

Comment: @Igor You cannot do it this way. `Value` is not nullable, it is `DateTime` and it will throw an exception if you try to access it this way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If all the values in the `DateIn` array are `null`, your code would throw a `NullReferenceException`.

You may use the [null-propagation-operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-) here:

```
string datetest = DOInfolist[i].RentalItem.SimCard.DateIn[u]?.ToShortDateString() ?? "Empty";
```

This operator (`?.`) now returns a nullable string. If `DateIn[u]` has a value, `ToShortDateString()` is called and the operator returns a nullable string with the returned value.
If `DateIn[u]` is `null` the operator returns `null`, too.

Comment: Requires C# 6.0 :-) (just as a note, the lucky among us can use it, the unluncky ones can't)

Comment: i installed C# 6 and this worked for me,
if I have multiple (?.) on the left side of ?? does it means that if any of the (?.) returns a null it will return the right side of the ??

Comment: @BloopieBloops That's right (though I can't tell 100% without seeing the real code). But thatswhy the null-conditional operator is also called null-propagation operator, because it propagates null through the expression. And if this expression is null at the end, the right side of the `??` is used (note that `??` is actually called ["null-coalescing"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) operator)

Answer (score 2):

You have a mistake. First check for `null` values by `HasValue` and use single `?` not double `??` like the following snippet:

```
string datetest = DOInfolist[i].RentalItem.SimCard.DateIn[u].HasValue ? DOInfolist[i].RentalItem.SimCard.DateIn[u].ToShortDateString() : "Empty";
```